# How can I perform accordion using slide toggle effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, slidetoggle

I have vertical menu,I want to perform accordion for this menu.
html code is

```
<ul id="menuLeft">
    <li id="ApplicationId" class="menu-li"><span><img src="../Images/tab_arrow.png"></span><a href="#">Application</a>
        <ul class="submenu-ul" style="display: none;">
            <li class="submenu-li"><span><img src="../Images/leftmenu_downarrow.png"></span><a href="#">Basic Information</a>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu-li"><span><img src="../Images/leftmenu_downarrow.png"></span><a href="#">Vipin</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="ReviewandSubmissionID" class="menu-li"><span><img src="../Images/tab_arrow.png"></span><a href="#">Review and Submission</a>
        <ul class="submenu-ul" style="display: none;">
            <li class="submenu-li"><span><img src="../Images/leftmenu_downarrow.png"></span><a href="#">Nithin</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

script is

```
$('.submenu-ul').hide();
$(document).on("click", ".menu-li", function () {
    var selected_li = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + selected_li + ' ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

My problem is when I click on one menu it shows its submenu, but at the same time If I click on the second menu it also showing its submenu without closing the first submenu.
How can I solve this issue?

**I edited my fiddle demo**

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7x5En/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide visible elements before opening new element.

Try:

Change

```
$u.appendTo($li);
```

to

```
$u.appendTo($li).hide();

$(document).on("click", "#" + value.MenuId, function () {        
    var selected_li = $(this).attr('id');        
    if(!($('#' + selected_li + ' ul').is(':visible'))){
        $('li ul:visible').slideUp();
    }
    $('#' + selected_li + ' ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7x5En/2/)

Comment: @Hiral- Plz find the new fiddle

Comment: I have a doubt. How can I set the image for slide up and slide down?

Answer (score 1):

In the click handler slide up all the other `submenu-ul` elements

```
var $subs = $('.submenu-ul').hide();
$(document).on("click", ".menu-li", function () {
    var selected_li = $(this).attr('id');
    var $ul = $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
    $subs.not($ul).stop(true, true).filter(':visible').slideUp();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Bft4k/)